# I can`t read the data after I update my rules on firestore (React Native)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

the rules I set is allow read: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;

how I call it is like this

```
return async (dispatch) => {
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("patients")
      .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
      .collection("patient")
      .orderBy("creation", "desc")
      .get()
      .then((result) => {
        let Patients = result.docs.map((doc) => {
          const data = doc.data();
          const id = doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
        dispatch({ type: GET_PATIENTS, Patients });
      });
  };
```

How can i fix it?

firebase rule

```
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /patients/{patientsID}{
        match /patient/{patientID}{
        allow read: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
        allow create: if request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
        allow update: if request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
        allow delete: if resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
        match /diagnostic/{diagnosticID}{
          allow read: if true;
          allow write: if request.resource.data.uid == request.auth.uid;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

image for the data

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ag7uBMx2FuEijuILje2xJIv8RawcFA?e=Gy6jeC

Comment: I tried to help below. If that's not it, can you edit your question (there's a link right under it) to include: 1) the minimal, complete rules with which to reproduce this problem (as the check could appear in many places), 2) a screenshot of a document you'd expect to get back with this query.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow and let you know it is late right now thank you for the help

Comment: did not work i will add the question with what you asked for it

Comment: it work now after i added indexing to the firebase thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules don't filter data on their own. Instead they merely ensure that the data that is being requested matches your rules.

So your query needs to match the rules, which means they also need to filter by UID:

```
  .collection("patient")
  .orderBy("creation", "desc")
  .where("uid", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
```